# How can I set the transform origin to the middle of this rectangle in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Trying to work my head around how I can rotate this rectangle from the dead centre only using D3.js and Javascript.

```js
const height = window.innerHeight - 20,
  width = window.innerWidth - 20;

var body = d3
  .select("body")
  .style("text-align", "center")
  .style("background", "#3c3c3c");

var svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("width", width)
  .style("background", "red")
  .style("display", "inline-block");

var g = svg.append("g")

// Currently the point of origin is the top left. How can I move this to the center?
var rect = g
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", width / 5)
  .attr("height", width / 5)
  .attr("transform", `translate(${width/ 2}, ${height/2}) rotate(0)`)
  .style("fill", "white")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `x` and `y` attributes of the `rect`. Since these give the top-left point, you can set the `rect` at the centre of the `svg` with:

```
// get centre of svg and rect width and height
var svgCentre = {x: width/ 2, y: height / 2};
var rectDims = {w: width / 5, h: height / 5};
var rect = g
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", svgCentre.x - (rectDims.w / 2)) // offset left by half rect width
  .attr("y", svgCentre.y - (rectDims.h / 2)) // offset up by half rect height
  .attr("width", rectDims.w)
  .attr("height", rectDims.h)
  .style("fill", "white");
```

Where `svgCentre` is half the width and half the height of the `svg`. Then you can offset the top-left point of the `rect` by half the width and half the height of the `rect`.

You mention you want to rotate the `rect` around the centre point - you can re-use the `svgCentre` coordinates in the `rotate` transform:

```
.attrTween("transform", () => {
  var i = d3.interpolate(0, 360); // full circle
  // set centre of rotation at centre of svg
  return t => `rotate(${i(t)}, ${svgCentre.x}, ${svgCentre.y})`; 
});
```

[`attrTween`](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#transition_attrTween) is figuring out that over the course of the transition you need to rotate through 360 degrees i.e. 5.55 degrees per millisecond. The `return t => ...` is saying return a function with an argument `t` which is some time in the `duration` that when passed to the `d3.interpolate` function (assigned to `i`) will resolve to the amount of degrees to rotate based on the time elapsed. This is then put into the string attribute of the `transform` for that moment in time.

Example:

```js
const height = window.innerHeight - 20,
  width = window.innerWidth - 20;

var body = d3
  .select("body")
  .style("text-align", "center")
  .style("background", "#3c3c3c");

var svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("width", width)
  .style("background", "red")
  .style("display", "inline-block");

var g = svg.append("g")

// get centre of svg and rect width and height
var svgCentre = {x: width/ 2, y: height / 2};
var rectDims = {w: width / 5, h: height / 5};
var rect = g
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", svgCentre.x - (rectDims.w / 2)) // offset left by half rect width
  .attr("y", svgCentre.y - (rectDims.h / 2)) // offset up by half rect height
  .attr("width", rectDims.w)
  .attr("height", rectDims.h)
  .style("fill", "white")

// rotate rect through 360 degrees with centre of rotation at svg centre
rect.transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .attrTween("transform", () => {
    var i = d3.interpolate(0, 360); // full circle
    // set centre of rotation at centre of svg
    return t => `rotate(${i(t)}, ${svgCentre.x}, ${svgCentre.y})`; 
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I see. Thank you Robin. I have been able to alter my code to reflect this. I have not yet come across doing this with a transition. I simply set the duration to 1 and the interpolate to 0,45. 

Can you explain a bit more about return t? What is t? I am not the most adept programmer. Thanks.

Comment: @AliShah - see my edit - `t` is the argument (some time) of an anonymous function returned by by the `attrTween` function.